# How to calculate the status of a task within a week

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I want to calculate the status of a task against end date. In my codes below in completed column it's displaying A = 0 instead of A = 1 as my result.

| ID | EndDate | Task | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-06-11 | Analysing | In progess |
| B | 2023-06-11 | Developing | Not started |
| C | 2023-06-11 | Training | In progress |
| A | 2023-06-11 | Marketing | Completed |

```
DECLARE @currentWeek int
SELECT @currentWeek = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
SELECT  
    Employee as ID, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN Status  = 'Completed'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) as Completed,
    (Sum(CASE WHEN Status  = 'In progress'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +    
    Sum(CASE WHEN Status  = 'Not started'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as Remaining,
    Sum(CASE WHEN EndDate  >  convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OverDue  
FROM Task
WHERE DATEPART(week, [EndDate]) = @currentWeek  and Status !=  'Completed' 
Group By Employee
```

Expected output when today's date is 2023-06-12

| ID | Completed | Remaining | Over due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 1 |